# Is the "verb tense" necessary here

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

I saw an example:

> He is back in power **after three years in opposition.**

The same way, can I write:

> He is working for Bob **after (working for) three years for me.**

Can I drop the words in the brackets?

Comment: The proper parse is "after working (for three years) for me".  You can't omit 'working' and the 1st 'for' because it crosses an embedding.